# Hotlink to hosted Mootools core & more library

Tags: mootools

**Question:** Is there any reliable/permanent link to the mootools core & more libraries?

I made an upgrade to a mootools slideshow and put it available [online](http://bokningkalender.se/en/opensource/mootools/slideshow/) if anyone needs. 
But would like to have a Google link in the `<head>` for the javascript library but there is none...

Actually very little can be found for Mootools under the [Google's Web developer library page](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#mootools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only mootools-core available at CDN, you can link this from Google:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
```

But [mootools more](http://mootools.net/more/) consists of too many packages which may increase file size even if you don't use them. And I don't think your slideshow needs all you've included in [mootools-more-1.3.2.1.js](http://mootools.net/more/08b1e4bde91a1a8a567ba36f029a7237)

There's actually a mirror for mootools.more with full selection of components at [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/), but I think it's better to keep own mootools-more-build at your site.

Comment: btw, this version on the google cdn is with compat layer. if you know what you are doing, add -nocompat to the filename.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a project that uses these resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-core-full-compat-yc.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools-more/1.4.0.1/mootools-more-yui-compressed.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I myself learned since I posted this question that one of the good features of MooTools is modularity. So actually having a big file with all the code defeats the purpose a bit. So nowadays I [use the builder](http://mootools.net/core/builder) and make my own version. Still thank you for sharing this! `+1`